# android 6 won't run in v23 (build-tools)

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, build-tools, samsung-edge

My app works on most androids, but in all the devices that run android 6.x.x it stops work at the splashscreen

I've installed the v23 build tools, I've this folders:

```
/Users/ricardo/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/
/Users/ricardo/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.2/
/Users/ricardo/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.3/
```

When I try to package the app, it's like it uses the v22:

```
Packaging application: /Users/ricardo/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/
```

I've tested iPhone 4, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6S, and this android devices:

[image: devices]

The last one is Samsung S7 Edge.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Build your app with SDK 5.2.2.GA. Also there is run-time permission issue for Android M.

Comment: The app is built by 5.2.2.GA, and have the targetSdkVersion set to 23, my module was build on 5.0.0.GA with v21, now I've changed to 5.2.2.GA and v23, but still the same while building the app

Comment: It that case it looks like run-time permission issue.

Comment: My client explained the issue the wrong way, the app only crash after my module it's loaded. But you think that could still be run-time permission issue?

Comment: Should I include this  <uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="...." /> ?https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissions/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: @Saeed Sharman, Thanks, I't was the permissions, in because I don't have any android 6.x.x and the simulator doesn't allow to use the camera and the flash, I've send this link to my client and it worked: http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

Answer (score -1):

Check your manifest, such trouble could be from there. Check all names and permissions, maybe you using something, that was not just deprecated, but removed from Android M

Comment: This is my manifest:  
            <application android:largeHeap="true"/>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>

Comment: and where your activities? like here: http://creativeandroidapps.blogspot.ru/2012/06/how-to-declare-activity-in-manifest.html

Comment: The activities came from the Titanium Module